# Fetch window handle from title using Java on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, window, handle

Is there any way to get the handle of a window using title with Java in Mac OS X?

Comment: `handle of a window ` can you please elaborate

Comment: Window handle can be defined as a pointer to an opened window which can be used to identify its various attributes for example its size. In windows programming with c# we use wnd.hwnd where wnd is of type windows and hwnd is the handle.

Comment: Are you trying to get a handle on a window of your Java application, or on another process window?